# Why is a one-to-one linear map from a finite-dimensional vector space to itself onto?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm aware that the rank-nullity theorem states that $\dim V = \operatorname{dim null}(T) + \operatorname{dim range}(T)$, but I'm unable to see how I can apply the theorem to get that a one-to-one linear map from a finite-dimensional vector space to itself is onto.

Comment: $T$ is one-to-one iff $null(T)=\left\{0\right\}$, which is $0$-dimensional. What is $\dim(range(T))$?

Comment: dim(range(T)) should be the dimension of the vector space, correct?

Comment: Yes. Then what happens if $W\subseteq V$ and $\dim W=\dim V$?

Comment: Then $W$ = $V$?

Comment: Yes. You need to think of dimension as a sort of ``size'' of a space. An analogy would be the following: If a subset $X$ of a finite set $Y$ has the same number of elements as $Y$, then $X=Y$.

Comment: The title and the body seem to be asking different questions. The answer to the question in the title is "By definition: one-to-one means that's injective and surjective", so I suspect that it may not be the real question. But the question in the body asks how to use a given theorem to prove something which is false, because there are linear maps from finite vector spaces to themselves which are neither injective nor surjective.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Usually one-to-one *map* means simply injective (as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function)), but I have definitely seen one-to-one used as bijective as you say (although I'd say people usually use "one-to-one *correspondence*" in this case). This is one of those language problems that could be easily avoided by using unambiguous words "injective" and "surjective". But I digress. Your point is valid imo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The range of $T$ is a subspace of the finite dimensional space $V$. It equals $V$ if and only if it has the same dimension as $V$. According to the rank-nullity theorem, it has the same dimension as $V$ if and only if the kernel of $T$ has dimension $0$, that is is $0$.

Hence, you may see the following equivalence thanks to the rank-nullity theorem:

A linear map from a finite-dimensional vector space to itself is onto in and only if it is injective (and so if and only if it is an isomorphism).

Comment: I was wondering what is meant by "into"?

Comment: I meant injective, the property that to any element in the image corresponds only one preimage. (English is not my main language - I may edit my answer to make it clearer).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f$ is not onto then there must exist a vector $x$ in $V$ having no pre-image in $V$, so $\vert f(V)\vert <\vert V\vert $.
It suggests that there must exist distinct $x_1$, $x_2\in V$ s.t. $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ i.e. $f$ is not one-one ($\mathbb\ contradiction$).

Hence $f$ is onto as well.